# Как обновить json файл с GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

Всем привет. Я пытаюсь сделать коммит json файла в гитхаб репозиторий. То есть мне надо обновлять периодически json файл. Я нашел один способ, с которым у меня получается сделать коммит, но только если текст формата plain text, а не json.

Надо сделать ПОСТ-запрос по адресу `https://api.github.com/repos/:user/:repo/git/trees` с телом:

```
{
   "base_tree": "{{sha-base-tree}}",
   "tree": [
      {
        "path": "fil1.json",
        "mode": "100644",
        "type": "blob",
        "content": "updated text"
      }
   ] 
}
```

Но, как видите, `content` принимает только plain text. Если туда передать текст формата json вот так:

```
{
   "base_tree": "{{sha-base-tree}}",
   "tree": [
      {
        "path": "fil1.json",
        "mode": "100644",
        "type": "blob",
        "content": "{"files": [{"image": "link"}]}"
      }
    ]
 }
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
{
   "message": "Problems parsing JSON",
   "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#create-a-tree"
}
```

Там в документации есть какие-то `Custom media types for blobs` https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/git#custom-media-types-for-blobs может быть это оно, не подскажите? Не получается разобраться как этим пользоваться. Спасибо

Comment: Не знаю, что здесь должно быть - ``"content": "{"files": [{"image": "link"}]}"``, но выглядит как слишком много одинаковых кавычек, которые открываются и закрываются не там,где надо.

Comment: @Эникейщик так в том-то и проблема. Надо передать туда как-то json, но не получается. Наверное нужен какой-то другой способ или это совсем нереально. Но я, кстати, нашел еще вот такой вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193327/github-api-update-json-file похоже, там парень хочет добиться того что и я. Но я не понял ответ совершенно ☹